# tabulator paginationElement styles problem

Tags: pagination, styles, tabulator

I have a question about `paginationElement` in Tabulator.

As per tabulator documentation, i created a `DIV` and used `paginationElement` in Table setup to render the paginator in the `DIV`. Well, it works. But with a drawback, no styling works, no colors, no highlighting of current page. So it is kinda inconvenient.

Is there a way to resolve this?

Otherwise, i am really happy with Tabulator! Thank you for the great work!

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You might have to style the pagination footer by css as the location of it has been changed by paginationElement.

Answer (score 0):

This is because all of the table styling is based around the pagination element being inside the table.

Moving it outside the table will mean you will need to apply the styles yourself. The classes that denote that you are on the current page etc will still be applied, you just need to tell the browser how to style them.

The [Styling Documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.6/style#css) contains more information on the classes used by tabulator and how to style the table

Comment: Thank you for the information. I missed that part. I solved my problem by modifying the css for the required elements directly. Now looks much better :)